# PostgreSQL установить пароль пользователю без пароля

Tags: postgresql

Не подскажете, как задать пароль пользователю базы, у которого изначально не было пароля?
Следующая команда выдает ошибку:

```
alter user user_name set password to "123";
```

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "password"
```

Comment: @Ainar-G Почему бы вам не оформить свой коментарий как ответ?

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки для "будущих поколений", пожалуйста.

Comment: @V-Mor добавил сам, у меня тоже postgres ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верный синтаксис:

```sql
ALTER USER user_name WITH PASSWORD '123456';
```

Документация: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-alteruser.html.